# Replacing more than two line breaks with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, textarea

I want to search my textarea for `"\n"` line breaks but I want two line spaces to be the maximum.

What formula can I use in this `regex` so that it looks for anything over three `\n`'s in a row ("`\n\n\n`") and replaces it with just one `<br>` ?

```
this.replace(new RegExp('\n', 'gim') , '<br/>');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
this.replace(new RegExp('(\n){3,}', 'gim') , '<br/>');
```

This will replace 3 or more \n's with a br, make that 4 if you want 4 or more.

Comment: `this.replace(/\n{3,}/g, '<br/>')`

Answer (score 2):

```
var newString = "some \n\n\n\n\n string".replace(/\n{3,}/g, '<br/>');

alert(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

`this.replace(new RegExp('\\n+', 'gim') , '<br/>');`

You can avoid using `RegExp` with:

`this.replace(/\n+/g, '<br />')`

Answer (score 0):

```
this.replace(/[\n]{3,}/g,'<br/>');
```